# Three.JS Panorama Doesn't Resize Properly on Mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, three.js, resize, window-resize

So I'm currently working with Three.Js and it's device orientation library to create a panorama that one can navigate by moving their phone. The issue I'm having is that this is what I want it to look like:

[Proper Panorama](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbbGh.jpg)

and when the page loads for the first time, it does this properly. However, when I refresh the page it turns to this:

[Panorama on Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgTAs.jpg)

My friend looked at it and said that it has something to do with the camera not resizing properly for mobile. But I've looked and can't find anything that goes in depth about what to do for the Camera Resize for mobile. Here's my code:

```
<script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/renderers/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>

(function() {
              "use strict"

              window.addEventListener('load', function() {

                    var container, camera, scene, renderer, controls, geometry, mesh;

                    var animate = function(){

                        window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                        controls.update();
                        renderer.render(scene, camera);

                    };

                    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

                    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100);

                    controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls( camera );

                    scene = new THREE.Scene();

                    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 16, 8 );
                    geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( -1, 1, 1 ) );

                    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/2294472375_24a3b8ef46_o.jpg' )
                    } );

                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    scene.add( mesh );

                    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 4, 4, 4 );
                    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff00ff, side: THREE.BackSide, wireframe: true } );
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
//                      scene.add( mesh );

                    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                    renderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
                    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Specific Camera Stuff

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

                        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                    }, false);


                    THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
                    controls.connect();

                    animate();

              }, false);

        })();
```

Any ideas of how to make it so that it resizes properly no matter what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the pixel ratio when you are creating the renderer:

```
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
```

Comment: Added it here to my code but nothing changed. 
     
     `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
       renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
       renderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
 container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);`

Comment: Try to campare size of canvas (width and height attributes of canvas element) and style-size (width and height params of style property of canvas element) of canvas before and after resize. If ratio of size to style-size changed after resize - then you need to correct it manually on resize.